# whats wrong with my php script

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, include

hello to all at stackoverflow. (my first post) : )
i wrote this script

```
$file = glob("*.php");  // list all .php files
$findfile = array_search("index.php", $file); // search array for index.php
unset($file[$findfile]);  // remove index.php from array
sort($file, SORT_NUMERIC); // sort array 
foreach($file as $file){ include_once($file);} // include files in page
```

the files are 1.php,2.php,3.php etc

everytime i run it the files get included at the top of the page.
i need the files in the middle,
what am i doing wrong.

Thats the whole page as it looks for now

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ta'])){
$ta = $_POST['ta'];
if($ta != "" && strlen($ta) > 1 ){
$ta = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 !?.,]#i', '', $ta);
$usertextinput = '<p class="important">'.$ta.'</p>';

$pho = count(glob('*.php'));
$username_file = ($pho + 1) . ".php";
$createuser = fopen($username_file, 'w');
fwrite($createuser, $usertextinput);
header("location: index.php#bottom");}}

$userpage = '<p class="important"><span>Posts\'s:</span><br />
[username] Has 1 post's To Date.</p>';?>

$file = glob("*.php");
$findfile = array_search("index.php", $file);
unset($file[$findfile]);
sort($file, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($file as $file){ include_once($file);}

$userpage .= '<form name="text" method="post" action="">
<textarea name="ta" placeholder=" Enter Your Comment\'s Here ">
</textarea><br />
<a name="bottom"></a>
<p class="sub"><input type="submit" value="Post To Page" /></p>';
?>
```

im building a post wall (no database)

Comment: im pretty sure wherever the foreach loop appears is where the files will be included, could you show the rest of the page?

Comment: Can we see your html to see where you want to include the files?

Comment: In the middle of what? Plus, this code is riddled with errors and you're not echoing your variable.

Comment: It's because this is next to impossible to test. I've fixed and tested your code to work, but I don't know where you're expecting it to echo out in the middle of (I don't know what). Do you have more code about what you posted?

Comment: I tested having this as test results `test asdfasdf asdfasdf Posts's: [username] Has 1 post's To Date.` I take it you want it to be `Posts's: [username] Has 1 post's To Date. test asdfasdf asdfasdf` correct?

Comment: Right now, I have the form on top, then `Posts's: [username] Has 1 post's To Date. test asdfasdf asdfasdf`, is that what you want?

Comment: Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go. It will have the form's input on top,
then the `Posts's: [username] Has 1 post's To Date.` followed by the included files.

It's basically a placement issue.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ta'])){
    $ta = $_POST['ta'];
if($ta != "" && strlen($ta) > 1 ){
    $ta = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 !?.,]#i', '', $ta);
    $usertextinput = '<p class="important">'.$ta.'</p>';

$pho = count(glob('*.php'));
$username_file = ($pho + 1) . ".php";
$createuser = fopen($username_file, 'w');
    fwrite($createuser, $usertextinput);
    header("location: index.php#bottom");
    }
}

$userpage = '<form name="text" method="post" action="">
<textarea name="ta" placeholder=" Enter Your Comment\'s Here ">
</textarea><br />
<a name="bottom"></a>
<p class="sub"><input type="submit" value="Post To Page" /></p>';

$userpage .= '<p class="important"><span>Posts\'s:</span><br />[username] Has 1 post\'s To Date.</p>';

echo $userpage;

$file = glob("*.php");
$findfile = array_search("index.php", $file);
    unset($file[$findfile]);
sort($file, SORT_NUMERIC);
    foreach($file as $file){
     include_once($file);
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just tick that little checkmark ;-) glad to have helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it isn't working, is because you are terminating the php code here:

```
[username] Has 1 post's To Date.</p>';?>
```

Remove the `?>` and escape the single quote near `post's`; so the code block will look like this:

```
$userpage = '<p class="important"><span>Posts\'s:</span><br />
[username] Has 1 post\'s To Date.</p>';

$file = glob("*.php");
$findfile = array_search("index.php", $file);
unset($file[$findfile]);
sort($file, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($file as $file){ include_once($file);}
```

Comment: tried that latheesan the include file is still at the top. thanks for your suggestion